# Problem Loading The Tkinter window for second time

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, frameworks

So I'm trying to make the main menu for a Tkinter app I've developed but here's the problem when I click one on the button to open the other file which is the other window it's ok but when I close that window and try to open it again by clicking on the same button in the main menu I get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\alireza\anaconda3\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "menu.py", line 32, in open_main
    root.destroy()
  File "c:\users\alireza\anaconda3\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2059, in destroy
    self.tk.call('destroy', self._w)
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "destroy" command: application has been destroyed
```

and this is my main menu file (menu.py):

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox


class Application:
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):


        self.mainframe = Frame(master, width = 300, height = 400, bg = 'slategray1')
        self.mainframe.pack()

        self.main_button = Button (self.mainframe, width = 25, height = 2,bg = "SteelBlue2" , text = "Customer Service", command = self.open_main)
        self.main_button.place(x= 55, y =50 )

        self.add_to_db_button = Button (self.mainframe, width = 25, height = 2,bg = "SteelBlue2" , text = "Add Item To Inventory", command = self.open_add_to_db)
        self.add_to_db_button.place(x= 55, y =100 )

        self.update_button = Button (self.mainframe, width = 25, height = 2,bg = "SteelBlue2" , text = "Update Inventory Items", command = self.open_update)
        self.update_button.place(x= 55, y =150 )

        self.about_button = Button (self.mainframe, width = 25, height = 2,bg = "sea green" , text = "Credits", command = self.about)
        self.about_button.place(x= 55, y =300 )

        self.close_button = Button (self.mainframe, width = 25, height = 2,bg = "navajo white" , text = "Quit", command = self.close_window)
        self.close_button.place(x= 55, y =350 )

    def close_window(self, *args, **kwargs):
        root.destroy()

    def open_main(self, *args, **kwargs):
        import main
        root.destroy()

    def open_add_to_db(self, *args, **kwargs):
        import add_to_db
        root.destroy()

    def open_update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        from update import AppUpdate
        root.destroy()

    def about(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("About Me", "Programmed and designed by Alireza Bagheri.")


root = Tk()
root.title("Main Menu")
root.resizable(False, False)
b = Application(root)
root.geometry("301x401+0+0")
root.mainloop()
```

I don't exactly know where the problem is so it would mean a lot to point me in the right direction

Comment: Don't rely on the `import` to open the windows for you.  The main issue is your codes structure... if you are building a project and is heavily reliant on `import`s you should always keep executable codes wrapped in functions like `func_add_to_db()` and then call `func_add_to_db()` within `open_add_to_db()` itself.  Your main code should also be wrapped in `if __name__ == '__main__':` blocks to avoid them being executed at `import`.  What you're experiencing is likely because you are always `destroy()`ing the main application so there's nothing to go back to `destroy()` again.

Comment: Read [Best way to structure a tkinter application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470842/7414759) and [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged)

Answer (score 0):

As Idlehands has commented, I don't think that you should rely on `import main` to build a window, but instead define a function (`build_window()` perhaps?) within main and then you can call it such as `main.build_window()`. This will ensure you know what code is supposed to execute, and may help avoid errors. I tried running your code, and could not replicate the error but instead encountered errors of:

1. `ImportError: No module named 'main'`
2. `ImportError: No module named 'update'`
3. `ImportError: No module named 'add_to_db'`

So this is not a minimum, verifiable, and complete example code of the error you are facing. The most we can do to help you is to speculate a solution. My speculation is if you want to "hide" a window that you will later return to, you should `.iconify()` it which will minimize it to the taskbar. If you call `.destroy()` on a Tkinter widget that widget will be deleted from memory, and if you would like another you will have to define it and `.pack()`, `.place()`, or `.grid()` it back onto the screen!